# How to combine two vtkImageData Objects?

Tags: vtk

For rendering purposes I need a vtkImageData object with two components where each component consists of the single component of two vtkImageData objects. How can I achieve that? Is there a vtkImageAlgorithm for this like http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/ImageData/vtkImageWeightedSum?

Thanks,

Dirk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use vtkImageAppend or vtkImageAppendComponents:

http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageAppend.html

http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageAppendComponents.html